# Select Between Date Range Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, date

I want to select records between 2 dates:

```
select * from orders where orders.created  <= '2015-07-31';
 select * from orders where orders.created >= '2015-07-01' and orders.created  <= '2015-07-31';
```

No results. If I do:

```
select * from orders where date(orders.created) >= '2015-07-01' and date(orders.created)  <= '2015-07-31';
```

Many results appear.Why?

```
mysql> select id,identifier,created from orders where date(orders.created) >= '2015-07-01' and date(orders.created)  <= '2015-07-31';
+-----+--------------+---------------------+
| id  | identifier   | created             |
+-----+--------------+---------------------+
| 366 | eu-126123916 | 2015-07-31 16:58:22 |
| 367 | eu-126127446 | 2015-07-31 17:43:14 |
| 368 | eu-126127510 | 2015-07-31 17:43:52 |
| 370 | eu-126134761 | 2015-07-31 18:56:07 |
| 371 | eu-126135814 | 2015-07-31 19:05:46 |
| 372 | eu-126144955 | 2015-07-31 20:34:48 |
+-----+--------------+---------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> describe orders;
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | bigint(19) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment    
| total               | float               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| totaltax            | float               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| totalpaid           | float               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ticket              | varchar(45)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| paypal_id           | varchar(45)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| note                | text                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| totaldocuments      | int(4)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sent_to_operator    | varchar(1024)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created             | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modified            | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |


22 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

My engine is TokuDB.

Comment: @oNare how is this different from the OP's second query?

Comment: Could you show some of those many?  Or put some of your data in [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d9739/3) fiddle to reproduce your issue (after it, post the new SQLFiddle link here)?

Comment: see the my edit

Comment: I forgot to say that my engine is TokuDB.

Comment: I know this is answered, but for future reference, could you post the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE Orders\G instead of DESCRIBE Orders - it gives output that you can cut and paste, unlike DESCRIBE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first query you do `...orders.created  <= '2015-07-31';` which is actually

```
orders.created  <= '2015-07-31 00:00:00';
```

since you have a timestamp or datetime datatype. Either use the `DATE()` function like you did in your other attempt, or write it like

```
orders.created  <= '2015-07-31 23:59:59';
```

Comment: Always use the second one. `DATE()` can not use index. (And you can tailor the datetime for some timezone modifications where `DATE()` cannot do that

Comment: And even better to use `< '2015-08-01';` to avoid any lost rows when/if you have microsecond accuracy in the column.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet:

```
where orders.created >= '2015-07-01'
  and orders.created  < '2015-07-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

This works for DATE, DATETIME, DATETIME(6), leap year, etc.
(Notice the `<`, not `<=`.)